# Retrieve as Model in Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Is it possible to take the results of any arbitrary query and cast them to any `ActiveRecord::Base` model, without using `Base.connection.execute`?

For example, given these models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos
end
```

If we run the a query like this, which loops back, we are stuck with `Bar` objects:

```
Foo.first
  .bars.joins(:foos) # => ActiveRecord::Relation [Bar, Bar, Bar...]
```

How can the query be made to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation [Foo, Foo, Foo...]`?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to return all the `foos` that's associated with the `bars` which the first `foo` is associated to?

Comment: Correct, though it's just an example scenario.  The key point is that I want to work with Foo objects, no Bar objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
Foo.joins(:bars).merge(Foo.first.bars).uniq
```

Comment: Interesting... So that works for this example, but what about a general case where you might want to "cast" the results to a specific model class?

Comment: if you feel lazy, you can always `pluck` the ids, and do a where on the model you want

Comment: Right, fair enough, but then I'm splitting it into multiple queries.  I'm just a little surprised there isn't an option like `Foo.first.bars.joins(:foos).as(Foo)` or something.